# How to refresh tabs in ionic 4

Tags: tabs, ionic4

I have a master - detail tab in `ionic 4`, the master tab gets the list of items that I've created in detail page, but when i create an item and i returned to the tab page, it doesn't refresh automatically.
I've tried using `ionDidEnter, ionWillEnter,` but nothing works.

This is my code in detail page:

```
async saveActividad() {

    await loading.present().then(async () => {
      await this.db.insertItem(item);
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1');
    });
}
```

And this is my code in master page `("tab1")`

```
ionViewWillEnter() {

      this.db.getItems()
      .then(
        (data) => {
          if (data !== '') {
            this.list = data;
          }
        }
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an TyPo in the event method call.

**Instead of:**

```
ionWillEnter() {
     // todo
}
```

**Try:**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
     // todo
}
```

**Ionic Page Events explanation**

> Name - Description

- ionViewWillEnter - Fired when the component routing to is about to animate into view.
- ionViewDidEnter - Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.
- ionViewWillLeave - Fired when the component routing from is about to animate.
- ionViewDidLeave - Fired when the component routing to has finished animating.

2) Or if only your tabs are just non-component based html, you could play with the *ngIf directive and invoke a method before returning true:

E.g.:

```html
<section class="master-detail" *ngIf='showIfAvailable();'></section>
```

```js
async showIfAvailable() {
      this.list = await this.db.getItems();
      if (list) {
          return true;
     }
}
```

Refresh data when function is invoked!

-Best Regards.

Comment: Yeah, it only works in pages, but doesn't work in tabs

Comment: @JonathanLopezLondoño If your tab is a component, it will work (tab1.component.ts).

What do you show that tab?

Comment: No, my tabs are from the tabs template, they don't have component.ts

Comment: @JonathanLopezLondoño Well then you should create the respective components with routing as indicated in the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs/

You also take advantage of lazy-loading, transitions with animations and lyfe hooks (route pass).

Comment: Read my latest update (alternative for you also in this scenario).

Comment: I have one more question, when i go between tabs, ionViewWillEnter is triggered, but when [I go from detail page to master page (tab 1) by using this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/tab1') ionViewWillEnter isn't triggered

Comment: @JonathanLopezLondoño You could use the following method: ngOnInit() (Angular OnInit lifecycle hook) or the other lifecycle events (like ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterContentChecked…) are fired a lot of times after router navigate. -Best regards.